# Disable discord "Incorrect command" error?

Tags: python, discord

I'm running a single bot on my server, but hoping to add another. However, I'm getting

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "[command]" is not found`

Obviously I'm going to get this error if a command doesn't exist, but it may exist on my other bot, so it's going to keep throwing out this error message.

It may not seem like a big deal, but there is any way I can disable this as it's going to fill up my terminal with these errors all of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can write a global [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) that just ignores these errors (or modify your existing error handler if you have one)

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        pass
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I'm still getting an error. Not sure why. I've put this in my bot.py file

Comment: @Jonathon Sorry, I used the wrong method name, it should be `on_command_error`.